# Multiple 'AND' conditions on same column

Tags: sql, asp.net, ms-access

I'm using an Access 2007 database in ASP.Net where I need to extract data from a table if an item meets multiple 'AND' clauses.

For example:

```
    Select * from tableA
    where tableA.column1 = myvalue1
    and (tableA.column2 = myvalue2
    and tableA.column2 = myvalue3)
```

(The '(' and ')' parenthesis around the 'and' clauses are an Access requirement)

myvalue1 exists multiple times in column1 because column2 stores many different pieces of data for the column1 value.

However, I only want the results to show those column1 values which meet all of the column2 search criteria.

For example, column1 contains employee surnames, column2 contains the qualifications of the employee.

One employee in column1 may hold many qualifications in column2.

Searching with the 'OR' clause for employees who hold all the required qualifications for an assignment would produce a table with multiple rows for each employee.

What is required is a single row for each employee who holds every one of the required qualifications.

Let's say employee A has qualifications X, Y and Z.  The employee's name will be in a row in column 1 each time a qualification is added to column2, so the employee's name appears in column1 3 times.  Assume now employee B also has qualifications X, Y and Z but employee C has W, X and Y.  If an assignment needs qualifications X,Y and Z I don't want employee C appearing in the results of a search as employee C won't hold the relevant qualifications.

When I use the above 'select' command with just one 'and' clause the search works fine, but with two 'and' clauses nothing is returned, even though I know there are items in column1 that meet both of the 'and' criteria.

What am I missing in the concatenation of the 'and' clauses?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want an OR between your 2nd and 3rd clauses? It's almost impossible for a column value to be equal to two different values. I would like to see an example of your data where column2 = value1 and column2 = value2

Comment: Can `tableA.column2 = myvalue2 AND tableA.column2 = myvalue3` in the same row? If not, then you need `OR` between them.

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: More details added and the expected results

Comment: What is required is a single row for each employee who holds every one of the required qualifications.  Add the following to your SQL: `GROUP BY column1 ORDER BY column1`

Comment: Unfortunately GROUP BY introduces an error 'cannot group by fields selected with '*'

Comment: This sentence: "One employee in column1 may hold many qualifications in column2" is troubling and requires explanation. Are you using a multi-valued field? What exactly are you doing in that column?

Comment: Erik I've updated the question to explain this in more detail

Answer (score 1):

The following solution will work, but performance will suffer. This will return 1 row per person, I can rewrite it to return both rows.

```
Select * from tableA
where tableA.column1 = myvalue1
and (tableA.column2 = myvalue2
and DCount("column2", "TableA", "column1 = """ & column1 & """ AND column2 = """ & myvalue3 & """" ) <> 0)
```

Your fundamental problem is that a select query without a group by or pivot clause only evaluates 1 row at a time. I'd probably pivot the data, concatenate it, and then evaluate it for better performance in the end. But that's more complicated, and requires more information on the table structure and what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks Erik, I've used a variation on Johnny's answer to get a working solution (see my answer elsewhere on the page). In the meantime I will try your approach as well to see if the overhead is lower..

Answer (score 1):

Based on new information, I'll submit this answer:

My gut feeling is that you can't do this in one simple query.  This sounds cludgy, but I think you're going to need one query created that's a SELECT DISTINCT query, and that query will pull one record for each employee:

```
Select DISTINCT Column1 from tableA
```

Call this query something like qryEmployees

Next you're going to need to create a new table.  Call it tblQualifications.  It will contain 2 fields; EName and EQualifications.  We're going to fill that in a minute.

Next you're going to need to loop through each record in qryEmployees and write the employee name and their qualifications into tblQualifications.

```
'Run through every Employee name
Do While qryEmployees.EOF = False
  'Set up a temp variable, MyQual, and set it equal to Empty
  MyQual = ""
  'Pull all qualifications from TableA for the current Employee
  Set rec = db.OpenRecordset ("Select Column1, column2 from TableA WHERE Column1 = '" & qryEmployees.Column1 & "'")
  'Looping through the qualifications
  Do While rec.EOF = False
    'Add the qualification to the MyQual string
    MyQual = MyQual & rec("Column2") & ", "
    rec.MoveNext
  Loop

  'Now that we have all the qualifications in a string, trim off the last ", "
  MyQual = left(MyQual, len(MyQual)-2)

  'Open up tblQualifications and fill it with the Employee and a string of all of their qualifications
  tblQualifications.AddNew
    tblQualifications(0) = qryEmployees.Column1
    tblQualifications(1) = MyQual
  tblQualifications.Update

'Move on to the next Employee and repeat the process
qryEmployees.MoveNext
Loop
```

Now you have one table with Employee Name in one field, and all of his qualifications in the next.  If you use the LIKE operator on this table, you should get your results.

```
Select * from tblQualifications
where tblQualifications.EName = myvalue1
and (tblQualifications.EQualifications LIKE myvalue2
and tblQualifications.EQualifications LIKE myvalue3)
```

It's not pretty, but it will work (with a little putzing with the code above, as I'm writing it off the top of my head and it's untested).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Johnny, your suggestion inspired me to write a slightly different approach to the solution.

I swapped the 'AND' to an 'OR' as others have suggested to extract any employee into a table if they have any of the qualifications.

The result is a table with every required qualification for every employee who has one of those qualifications.

I then did a count elsewhere of the number of qualifications required for the assignment and compared this to whether or not the employee had the required number of qualifications, as follows:

```
    Dim objSearchTable As DataTable = DSSearch.Tables("Employees")

    Dim i As Integer

    If QualificationsCount > 0 Then

        For i = 0 To objSearchTable.rows.count - 1

            strEmployee = objSearchTable.Rows(i).Item("column1")

            Dim foundRows As DataRow() = objSearchTable.[Select]("column1 = '" & strEmployee & "'")

            Dim numberOfRecords As Integer = foundRows.count

            If numberOfRecords < QualificationsCount Then

                objSearchTable.Rows(i).Delete

            End If

        Next

    End If

    objSearchTable.AcceptChanges
```

This deletes every instance of an employee from the table if the count of qualifications is less than the number required.

The solution isn't as elegant as extracting only the correct employees from the database to begin with.

There is also an overhead on extracting every employee from the database, but the end result is a table with just one row for each employee with all the qualifications, which does what I need.